# codeigniter sticky forms

Tags: codeigniter, webforms

I just started using CI today.. I normally use CakePHP but a whole lot of smaller projects needed something less "bulky".

What is the easiest way to implement sticky forms (retain user input after reload) in CI?

I currently have a whole lot of radio buttons for multiple choice quiz and some other text fields and when validation fails the data is lost...

I probably don't need to use session vars as I am not redirecting, I am simply loading the view upon validation failure, so the data should be available in $_POST..

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Validation library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html)?  Most of CodeIgniter's built-in form handling is there.  Use the [Form Helper's](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) `set_value()` function to reset the values after the form is reloaded:

```
<input type="text" name="somefield" value="<?php echo set_value('somefield', 'default'); ?>" size="50" />
```

Note that for `set_value()` to work, you need to run validation *on that field.*  If you don't need to validate every field in your form, you can set an empty rule, just to make the Validation library aware of that field:

```
$this->validation->set_rules(array('somefield' => ''));
```

For the radio buttons, see the Form Helpers `set_radio()` function.

Answer (score -2):

Use javascript for validation instead of refreshing the page.

Comment: Because nobody ever browses with JavaScript turned off.

Comment: I'd rather take care of the 95% of people with javascript turn on to make their experience more pleasurable than to gimp the site's responsiveness for the 5% that don't.
http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: I like to use both. If the user has javascript enabled, I use ajax to quickly give feedback. If not, I use php.

Comment: Client-side validation with JS is great, but you still have to validate data on the server. Rule #1 of web security is "don't blindly trust submitted data."